# Can I have a has-many-through association via a parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I've built a form that lets a user set up a storefront on our app. It works fine.

I'm now trying to add the ability to associate questions with products. Not every question will be applicable to every product. For example, if a storefront is selling a T-shirt, an applicable question might be "What size are you?".

Here is a basic diagram of my models:

[image: Basic model diagram]

Here are the relevant lines from my model classes:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :storefront
  has_many :questions
end

class Storefront < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :questions, through: :organizations
  has_many :products, class_name: Product::Base, dependent: :destroy
end

class Product::Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :storefront
  has_many :product_question_applicabilities
end

class ProductQuestionApplicability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product,  inverse_of: :product_question_applicabilities
  belongs_to :question, inverse_of: :product_question_applicabilities
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :answers
end
```

I'm having trouble setting up my form to accept attributes for the new Questions model.

Here is what my form looks like (stripped down to the relevant lines):

```
<%= form_for @storefront, url: create_or_edit_storefront_path(@storefront) do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |ff| %>
    <%= render 'question_fields', f: ff %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'add question', f, :questions, :class => "add-question new-thing flat-link" %>

<% end %>
```

This gives me an error "ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError in Storefronts#edit,  Could not find the association :organizations in model Storefront"

Have I set up my models correctly to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need accepts_nested_attributes_for added to your models

try changing

```
class Storefront < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :questions, through: :organizations
  has_many :products, class_name: Product::Base, dependent: :destroy
end
```

to

```
    class Storefront < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :organization
      has_many :questions, through: :organizations
      has_many :products, class_name: Product::Base, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
   end
```